# Print the perl script's path without resolving symlink

Tags: perl

How do I print the script's directory path **without** resolving the symlink?

EDIT: I realized from below comment that it is not possible using FindBin, but is there a way around to get the script's directory ?

```
use FindBin;
use Cwd;
use Cwd 'abs_path';
use File::Spec::Functions qw( rel2abs );
BEGIN
{
   push @INC, "$FindBin::Bin";
}
print "rel2abs:";
print rel2abs("$FindBin::Bin");
print "\n";

print "abs_path:";
print abs_path("$FindBin::Bin");
print "\n";
```

This script prints:

```
/tmp/one/two$ perl 3/symlink_to_four/test.pl 
rel2abs:/tmp/one/two/3/four
abs_path:/tmp/one/two/3/four
```

I want it to print */tmp/one/two/3/symlink_to_four*

```
 /tmp/one/two/3$ ls -l
 four
 symlink_to_four -> four
```

Why I need this: samba is configured in the Linux box where my Perl script is going to run, if I replace first portion of the Linux path with `\\linux-machine-name`
 and rest of `/` with `\`, I get windows path, which I will save it in a file and will get consumed by other script, for instance, in the above example, I am trying to convert `/tmp/one/two/3/symlink_to_four` to `\\linux-machine-name\one\two\3\symlink_to_four`, I know how to figure-out the `linux-machine-name`, I don't want the resolved path, because I cannot figure out the windows equivalent path with resolved path, only `\\linux-machine-name\one\two\3\symlink_to_four` is valid, not `\\linux-machine-name\one\two\3\four`, it's how samba is configured.

Comment: `FindBin` always resolves symlinks. Why do you want to use the link name?

Comment: Also, `$FindBin::Bin` is always an absolute path, so passing it to `rel2abs` or `abs_path` is redundant.

Comment: it's complex to explain :(, my script has to pass-in the path without resolving the symlink to other script

Comment: It can't be done with `FindBin`, unless you modify [the source](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/perl-5.22.0/lib/FindBin.pm). This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); you'll probably get better answers if you explain exactly why you need to do this.

Comment: if we replace first dir name of the unix path with filer name and change / to \, then we will get windows path, symlink should not be accounted for the same. I can use something equivalent instead of findbin if needed. thanks.

Comment: Do you need `$FindBin::Bin` or `$ENV{PWD}`?

Comment: Thanks, no, $ENV{PWD} will not help, as I need the location of the script even if I execute it from different location.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Thanks for the help, I updated the title and content, hope I explained the problem in a better way now.

Comment: @Krish I don't understand your comment about converting from a Unix to a Windows path. Do you mean something like `/c/cygwin/foo` -> `c:\cygwin\foo`? Please give an example. Also, what do you want to do if there are multiple symlinks pointing to your script? Which one do you want to use? Finally, I'm still not clear *why* you need to do this. Can you try to explain in more detail? It might be best to [edit] these details into your question instead of responding via comments.

Comment: done editing, there will be only one symlink'ed dir in the path to my script. thanks.

Comment: @Krish Thanks for the edit, your question is much clearer now. One more question: why can't you use the resolved path? Is it because the symlink is in your samba share, but the resolved path is not?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this again, in the example shown above, only `\\linux-machine-name\one\two\3\symlink_to_four` is available from windows side, `\\linux-machine-name\one\two\3\four` is not, because that's how samba is configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you're trying to achieve, you can do it with [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Tiny;


my $path =  path(__FILE__);

print $path->absolute->parent, "\n";
```

Path::Tiny's `realpath` method would resolve symlinks, but the `absolute` method does not.

`__FILE__` is a special token that resolves to the name of the Perl source file it's contained in (either your main script or a module it loads).  You could also use `$0` which is the name of the script being executed.  Either of these could be absolute or relative depending on whether the script was invoked with a relative or an absolute path.

If your scripts are always invoked with an absolute path then you could just use `$0` and not bother with an extra module.

Comment: Thanks, it will be easy if I can achieve this without installing Path::Tiny or any other new perl module.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cwd::abs_path to get an absolute path.
Cwd is a core-module so you don't need to install anything extra.

```
use Cwd qw(abs_path);
my $absolute_path = abs_path (readlink $link);
```

https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977420